# Webrtc ECONNREFUSED

Tags: android, websocket, webrtc

I have gone through the stack questions before and then posting this as i am still facing some ambiguities.
Right now I am facing this error while connecting my client android device to locally hosted server(localhost:8080)
I think its probably because of the TURN navigation but am not sure.Can you please help me out of this.

P.S. I have been following these instructions to build the server locally 
::the github repo for appr.tc/

Error:: The following is the error that I received once I tried connecting my AndroidRTC client application to the apprtc signalling server locally created::
alphapronto(name of the room)

E/RoomRTCClient:Room connection error: HTTP POST to http://localhost:8080/r/alphapronto error: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080) after 8000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: Have you tried to use ssl with an (self-signed) certificate?

Remeber that using localhost-adresses on android can be problematic: Android runs on his own machine and it seems, that the device tried to connect to his own localhost-adress. Can you use an ip instead?

Comment: I have tried using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost as it is understood by the dvm differently but not ssl. Can u tell me how to go with that.I can tell you that right now my server is working just fine as I am able to connect two browser windows ( as two client) over the server locally however the problem arises when i try to connect my android client over that